# How to disable auto generated title bar from maximized child in MDI parent?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that is maximized on load inside a MDI parent. That form has no title bar i.e. `FormBorderStyle = None`.

BUT when that form is maximized in its MDI parent, even though it has no title bar, the following situation occurs (see image below)

[image]

Black arrow : MDI parent title bar ;
Red Arrow : The buttons that are automatically created on my MDI menustrip bar.  I want to delete those 3 buttons... Because I don't want the child form to be either resized or closed.

How can I do that ?

Comment: I think it might be the control box property on your form. Set this to false.

Comment: @Wheels73 Awesome. That's what I needed. Thank you. Post an answer if yu want.

Comment: Have done... thanks for that!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be the control box property on your form. 
Set this to false